# Difference between constrained and confined

Tags: word-choice

Regarding this matter, I've googled and came up with [this website](http://www.wikidiff.com/constrained/confined), which says:

> As **verbs** the difference [...] is that confined is (confine) while constrained is (constrain).
>   As adjectives the difference [...] is that **confined is not free to move while constrained is within close bounds** [...]

With the first paragraph it is that I simply do not understand it grammatically.
I read the second one as confined is stricter than constrained.
**Is this correct?**

My guess would be that "constrained" may refer to virtually any situation while "confined" is only applied to physical space.

Comment: That web site doesn't get it quite right.  A dog is constrained by a chain but confined by a fence.  More generally, a constraint limits the type and extent of action one might take, while a confinement limits the range of possibilities of action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between **confine** and **constrain**.

**confine**:

> To restrict; to keep within bounds; to shut or keep in a limited space or area.

**constrain**:

> To force physically, by strong persuasion; to compel; to oblige.

And as a noun confine means limit.([confine and constrain](http://the-difference-between.com/constrain/confine))

Comment: It is encouraged to post a link and name of the source. Please edit your answer.

Comment: It looks far better. +1) :-)

Comment: Alright, these are two definitions, but could you explain the **difference** between both somewhat more, please?

Comment: The definitions are quite clear, but as adjectives **confined** means
(of a space or an area) small and surrounded by walls or sides. For example: *"It is cruel to keep animals in confined spaces"*. (Oxford dictionary) And **constrained** means to feel very strongly that you must do something. For example: *"I feel constrained to tell the truth"*. (Longman dictionary)